# Monitor is going sleep mode while Raspberry Pi is connected via HDMI

Tags: pi-2

I am new to Raspberry Pi. I am using Raspberry Pi 3. Last night I connected my monitor via HDMI to my Raspberry Pi. But today I am trying to connect again and this time the monitor is going to sleep mode. What is the problem?

**Note:** I can connect my laptop to the monitor and it's fine.

Comment: Is the display on initially and it is going to sleep after a time interval or is it not coming on at all?

Have you power cycled the Pi in between plugging in the monitor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You powered it up without the monitor plugged in, and you do not have:

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
```

in `/boot/config.txt`.  According to [the documentation](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/configuration/config-txt/video.md), this:

> ...pretends that the HDMI hotplug signal is asserted, so it appears that a HDMI display is attached. In other words, HDMI output mode will be used, even if no HDMI monitor is detected.

Without this, plugging in a display may not be effective.